# How to get reference to the main view in UIViewController in story board

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to iOS & Xcode development.

I have created a new story board project showing a blank screen. I need to add other subview to the main view programmatically from my UIViewController.

In order for me to fire `addSubview:containerView` I need first to get hold to a reference to the main View. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewController, do as following to add the subview,

```
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

Comment: Thanks .. I tried this but I'm keep getting run time error "bad access"